# Debug the DLL of an EXE using IDA Freeware

Tags: ida, debugging, dll, breakpoint

I'm trying to debug a DLL that is called in an executable file. I put the DLL in Ida Free and defined the breakpoints, and set 'Application' to the executable path. When I start the debug, the breakpoints never be hit.

[image]

I noticed that the output has the following:
7FF9D9A862B6: breakpoint vanished from memory
7FF9D9A862DB: breakpoint vanished from memory
7FF9D9A9175A: breakpoint vanished from memory
7FF9D9A917C8: breakpoint vanished from memory
7FF9D9A951C6: breakpoint vanished from memory
7FF9D9A951C8: breakpoint vanished from memory
7FF9D9A951F4: breakpoint vanished from memory

It's very strange, until yesterday I was able to debug perfectly, I turned off the computer and I can't do it anymore, the breakpoints are not activated.
In the end, the debug is closed and the executable opens perfectly.

Comment: Is your DLL loaded at a different address in IDA and in the process?